# SWT Arm Event not working

Tags: java, events, swt, listener

I am working on a program that needs to know when a menu is expanded so that it's contents can be updated (it lists the currently available serial ports). I am using SWT and setup a listener for the parent menu items Arm Event.

I created a demo program to show what I want.

```
package test.window;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

public class Test {

protected Shell shell;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Test window = new Test();
        window.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");

    Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
    shell.setMenuBar(menu);

    MenuItem mntmNewSubmenu = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
    mntmNewSubmenu.setText("New SubMenu");

    Menu menu_1 = new Menu(mntmNewSubmenu);
    mntmNewSubmenu.setMenu(menu_1);

    MenuItem mntmItem = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Item 1 selected");
        }
    });
    mntmItem.setText("Item 1");

    MenuItem mntmPorts = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.CASCADE);
    mntmPorts.addArmListener(new ArmListener() {
        public void widgetArmed(ArmEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Ports armed");
        }
    });
    mntmPorts.setText("Ports");

    Menu menu_2 = new Menu(mntmPorts);
    mntmPorts.setMenu(menu_2);

    MenuItem mntmPort = new MenuItem(menu_2, SWT.NONE);
    mntmPort.addArmListener(new ArmListener() {
        public void widgetArmed(ArmEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Port 1 armed");
        }
    });
    mntmPort.setText("Port 1");
    mntmPort.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Port 1 selected");
        }
    });

    MenuItem mntmPort_1 = new MenuItem(menu_2, SWT.NONE);
    mntmPort_1.setText("Port 2");
    mntmPort_1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Port 2 selected");
        }
    });

    MenuItem mntmItem_1 = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmItem_1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Item 2 selected");
        }
    });
    mntmItem_1.setText("Item 2");

}
}
```

I'd expect "Ports armed" to be printed right before the menu items "Port 1" and "Port 2" are shown. That would give my program a chance to change what "Port 1" and "Port 2" actually are.

For me, "Ports armed" is never printer (nor is "Port 1 armed") but the select events are fired when the items are clicked.

I'm testing this on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: strange, it works for me on Ubuntu 13.04 using `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux-3.3.0-v3346`

Comment: I tried downloading various version. I started on 4.3 and tried 3.7 and 3.3 jars with no avail. I downloaded the SWT binary from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/ and added the JAR to my build path in eclipse. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: No idea, works with 4.3 as well

Comment: Possibly Java version? I'm using 1.7 OpenJDK.

Comment: tried with OpenJDK 1.7 and works

Comment: Could you export the project as a Jar for me to try and run? That way I can know if its a build problem or a problem with my computer.

Comment: I just tested the demo program on another computer running Ubuntu 13.04 and it still doesn't work. It never print's Ports armed

Comment: well, I ran it from eclipse, may that's the difference?

Comment: I'm also running from Eclipse. I tried this snippit http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet152.java and the showListner is working but the armListener never gets called. I think I should be able to just use the show event for what I want though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I never got the Arm event to fire, the Show event worked well enough for me.

An example of the Show, Hide, and Arm listeners can be found here http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet152.java